# making a get request with python's requests library

Tags: python-requests, postman

I have to make a get request at https://isbnsearch.org/ to fetch books details from the given isbn number.
The query url looks like this

```
https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/<ISBN number>
```

when i make a get request from POSTMAN ,things work as desired..but doesnt work with requests.
my code looks like this

```
url = 'https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/9788170289265'
requests.get(url)
```

this comes up with a status code of 403.If its forbidden for 'requests' ,why not for postman.?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the site you are requesting does not support the default python-requests `User-Agent` which is `python-requests/2.25.0` or whatever version you are using. Changing the `User-Agent` seems to work:

```
import  requests

url = "https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/9788170289265"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Can confirm, just tested from my side and it returned a 200 with the correct html.